# How to create a stacked bar graph in kibana?

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

I have data in JSON format like this in my elasticsearch:

```
{
    "features": [
          {
            "feature": "A",
            "Yes": 19,
            "No": 0,
            "Maybe": 81
          },
          {
            "feature": "B",
            "Yes": 0,
            "No": 0,
            "Maybe": 100
          },
          {
            "feature": "C",
            "Yes": 10,
            "No": 32,
            "Maybe": 58
          }
        ]
    }
```

From this, is it possible to obtain a stacked chart as follows?
[image]